# How to find out if user got "Activity tracking" and / or "private mode" on

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, privacy

I am trying to find out if the user got his activity tracking disabled or not >> and also if a user is browsing in private mode...

```
if(navigator.doNotTrack != "unspecified"){
    // do something if the user disabled his activity tracking
}
```

but this works only in Mozilla Firefox...

Could anyone give me a hint what I can do to check also a status like that in Google Chrome and Safari (maybe also in IE)

another idea: try to save anything on users machine like a cookie or something into his local storage <-- but my knowledge about things like that are to small...

My thing is more PHP, HTML, and CSS

Thank you very much for any hints or help!

Thx

Comment: Note that ways to detect private browsing mode are considered bugs in the browser, and are usually fixed soon after being found.

Comment: but we have functions which are only working if the user got his activity protection disabled and if the user is surfing in normal mode and we have to inform the user about this situation then...

Comment: Note that Do Not Track and Private Browsing are entirely different things, and the former is easy to detect. In particular, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/doNotTrack contradicts your claim that navigator.doNotTrack works only in Firefox. You're just not doing the check correctly.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: @zero298: inform the user that he got his do not track option enabled....

Comment: @JosephSible: yes you are right, but now i am looking for a new way which works

Comment: That's begging the question.  What do you hope to do with the knowledge that a user has do not track enabled?  What is your endgame?  Are you going to ask them to disable it?  What if they don't?  Does your app fail?  I would expect the user to just not use your app at that point.  Why do you need to tell them?  They probably know they have it enabled, **they enabled it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph Sible said, you shouldn't be able to detect private browsing - it will look indistinguishable from a new user. You could look for the *absence* of a cookie, but that won't be reliable. I'd give up on this if I were you.

Detecting Do Not Track is easy in PHP:

```
function doNotTrack()
{
    return $_SERVER !== null && array_key_exists('HTTP_DNT', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER['HTTP_DNT'] === '1';
}
```